# Video doesn't play on site but it does somewhere else

Tags: html, html5-video

I'm working on a website with a HTML5 `video` tag. The video doesn't play on the website. But if I test it somewhere else, it plays without a problem.

http://carflow-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/

My code is here:

```
<video class="video-splash__video" width="720" height="405" autoplay="" poster="http://carflow-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/framework_wp/img/videoCarflowBackground.png">
    <source src="http://carflow-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/framework_wp/video/videoCarflowBackground.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    <source src="http://carflow-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/framework_wp/video/videoCarflowBackground.ogg" type="video/ogg">
    <source src="http://carflow-staging.houston-1.hybridmedia.be/wp-content/themes/framework_wp/video/videoCarflowBackground.webm" type="video/webm">
    Your browser does not support the video tag or the file format of this video.    
</video>
```

What could be the issue?

Comment: Possibly: _In some browsers (e.g. Chrome 70.0) autoplay is not working if no `muted` attribute is present._ [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/video#Attributes)

Comment: There's an error: `net::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID` Your site is using Common Name (CN) which Chrome will ignore now. https://serverfault.com/a/880809

Comment: I've tried to play the video with jQuery, but now I get an error Uncaught (in promise) DOMException

Comment: It seems that Chrome has issues with playing html5 video's. Don't know a solution yet